# How to use @error directive in Laravel Blade Component

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I'm trying to create some reusable component for CSS. Now, I'm stuck here.

**Anonymous Components**

```
<input {{ $attributes->merge(['class' =>'block w-full px-3 py-2.. @error('name') invalid @enderror ']) }} />
```

It does not work and throws errors:

```
syntax error, unexpected identifier "name", expecting "]"
```

**Does anyone know how to solve this error or alternative way to figure out ?**

Comment: did you try that `<div {{ $attributes->class(['p-4', 'bg-red' => $hasError]) }}>
    {{ $message }}
</div>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blade's compiler will not catch the `@error` directive inside the mustaches

```
{{ @error('name') invalid @enderror }}
```

```
<input
@error('name')
  {{ $attributes->merge(['class' => 'block w-full px-3 py-2 invalid']) }}
@else
  {{ $attributes->merge(['class' => 'block w-full px-3 py-2']) }}
@enderror
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input {{ $attributes->class(['form-control', 'is-invalid' =>  $errors->has($name)]) }} name="{{ $name }}" value="{{ old($name, $value) }}">
```